# Linking number of specific Reeb orbits in a toric domain ($S^3$ diffeomorphic)

Tags: symplectic-topology, contact-topology

Consider a toric domain defined by the region bounded on the first quadrant by a function $f:[0,a]\mapsto [0,b]$ with $a,b>0;f(0)=b,f(a)=0,f(x)>0 \hspace{2mm} \forall x\in [0,a)$. We know that $\forall x$ s.t. $f'(x)\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x\in (0,a)$, the torus $T^2$ in the fiber of $(x,f(x))$ is foliated by Reeb orbits which "wind $v_1$ and $v_2$ times", in the respective directions on the torus induced by the angle coordinates coming from the Arnold-Liouville Theorem. Take any one of these orbits and call it $o_{v_1,v_2}$ Likewise, we have that the singular fibers over the points $(0,b)$ and $(a,0)$ (which are topologically $S^1$) are also Reeb orbits, call them $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$. The claim I would like to prove is:
$$link(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)=1$$
$$link(\gamma_1,o_{v_1,v_2})=-v_2$$
$$link(\gamma_2,o_{v_1,v_2})=v_1$$
$$link(o_{v_1,v_2},o_{w_1,w_2})=min(-v_1w_2,-v_2w_1)$$

The first case can be deduced from the fact that, by taking stereographic projection of $S^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ on a point of $\gamma_2$, we get that $\gamma_2,\gamma_1$ turn into the z-ax and a circle in the xy-plane around the z-ax (by istopy think of it as the circle $x^2+y^2=1$), respectively. From this we get the result.

Now the second case I'm almost sure that comes by perturbing isotopically the orbit  $\gamma_1$ to the embedded loop in the torus above $(x,f(x))$ given by the direction $(0,1)$ and the minus comes from orientation considerations (this perturbation process can certainly be done trough all $x\in (0,a)$ because there is an easy identification of these tori, to make the leap form (0,a) to [0,a) we take the projection of the torus above $(x,f(x))$ into its first angle coordinates for $x$ small enough, and notice that this can be effectively done by considering the family of tori foliating $\mathbb{R}^3$ and degenerating at the image of the orbits $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ by the stereographic projection.

Now the last case is the one puzzling me, because by the same logic we could translate one orbit in a torus isotopically to one orbit into  another torus containing the other orbit, and then in my mind, the linking number should be the sum $-v_1w_2-v_2w_1$.

I appreciate any help with this case, and in the case of any of the other arguments being wrong I would like a correction.

To give you some context, this has been extracted from the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.6647.pdf page 24. Also, the angle coordinates and the toric domain is defined as the preimage of the region described at the beggining by the map
$$p:\mathbb{C}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$$
$$p(z_1,z_2)=(\pi|z_1|^2,\pi|z_2|^2)$$.

Comment: So, it turns out that I already received an answer on MathStack, in any case, here's the link if anyone is interested 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219149/linking-number-of-specific-reeb-orbits-in-a-toric-domain-s3-diffeomorphic